# lastInsertId retorna 0 (zero)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso obter o ID do meu último INSERT no banco, porém a função *lastInsertId()* só me retorna 0.

Essa é minha classe que conecta ao banco:

```
<?php 
namespace App\model;

class ModelConexao{
    
    public function conecta() {
        
        try {

            $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB."","".USER."","".PASS."",array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

            $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            return $pdo;
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            
            echo "Falha ao tentar conectar-se ao banco de dados. Erro: " . $e->getMessage();

            exit();
        }
    }
}
 ?>
```

Essa é minha classe que insere os dados no banco:

```
<?php 
namespace App\model;

use App\model\ModelConexao;

class ModelCadastro extends ModelConexao {
    
    public function insert($email, $senha){

        $sql = $this->conecta()->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGIN SET email=:email, senha=:senha");

        $sql->bindParam(":email",$email,\PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sql->bindParam(":senha",$senha,\PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sql->execute();

        return $this->conecta()->lastInsertId();
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: `$this->conecta()->lastInsertId()`, por que abriu uma nova conexão com o banco para pegar o último id?

Comment: Então @Woss eu imaginei que isso pudesse estar errado, porém, quando eu faço $sql->lastInsertId() está dando o seguinte erro: " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId() "

Comment: Isso porque `$sql` é o retorno de `prepare`, não `conecta`.

Comment: Entendi. Como ficaria então? Eu tentei $conexao = $this->conecta(); Antes do prepare e no final eu fiz $conexao->lastInsertId(); Que também me resultou zero.

Comment: @Woss agora eu consegui irmão. Primeiro eu peguei a conexão: $conexao = $this->conecta(); Depois eu utilizei essa variável para fazer o "prepare": $conexao->prepare... e por fim consegui o ID: $conexao->lastInsertId(); TOPZER!!! Muito obrigado meeeesmo. Estou tentando setar sua resposta como válida mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira adotada é que em cada `$this->conecta()` tem uma nova instância da classe `PDO` utilizado pra abstrair conexão com um banco de dados, após chamar esse método novamente para resgatar o último `id` inserido é uma nova instância de um nova conexão. Solução rápida:

```
<?php 
    namespace App\model;

    use App\model\ModelConexao;

    class ModelCadastro extends ModelConexao {    
        public function insert($email, $senha)
        {
            $conn = $this->conecta(); //pega a instância e utiliza no decorrer do código
            $sql = $conn
               ->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGIN SET email=:email, senha=:senha");
            $sql->bindParam(":email",$email,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->bindParam(":senha",$senha,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();
            return $conn->lastInsertId();
        }
    }
?
```

a solução ao meu ver ideal não é fazer herança porque a cada classe que precise utilizar uma conexão com o banco de dados será uma nova instância, geralmente o ideal é sempre trabalhar com apenas uma conexão em cada requisição, tendo um melhor desempenho e economia de recurso do banco de dados.

---

Eu utilizaria injeção e não herança, diminuiria acoplamento e faria com que a classe conexão seja compartilhada em todas as classes que assim precise de operação com o banco de dados, exemplo:

```
<?php 
    namespace App\model;

    class ModelConexao {
        private $pdo;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->conecta();
        }
        
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->pdo;
        }
        
        private function conecta() 
        {           
            try {

                $this->pdo = new \PDO(
                    "mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB."","".USER."","".PASS."",
                    array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(
                    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                    \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {            
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

---

```
<?php 
    namespace App\model;

    use App\model\ModelConexao;

    class ModelCadastro {
            
        private $conn;
        
        public function __construct(PDO $conn)
        {
            $this->conn = $conn;
        }
        
        public function insert($email, $senha)
        {           
            $sql = $this->conn
                ->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGIN SET email=:email,senha=:senha");
            $sql->bindParam(":email",$email,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->bindParam(":senha",$senha,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();
            return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        }
    }
?>
```

***Utilizando:***

```
$conexao = new ModelConexao();
$cadastro = new ModelCadastro($conexao->getConnection());
$cadastro1 = new ModelCadastro1($conexao->getConnection());
```

Comment: Entendi @novic . Gostei da preocupação com acoplamento, porém cada `Controller` tem apenas um `Model` e todos os métodos estarão em um mesmo `Model`. Dessa forma que você citou, eu entendo que toda vez que eu instanciar esse mesmo `Model` eu estarei fazendo uma conexão com o banco também, porque a requisição com o banco está no método construtor do `Model`. Certo?

Comment: @EPCriação na verdade há uma preparação na camada de abstração não hora do `execute` é feito uma conexão. O que importa é o baixo acoplamento e uma única instância com o banco de dados. e se algum dia tiver mais model, que talvez no primeiro momento não tem, é bom utilizar assim.

Comment: Entendi @novic , muito obrigado por sua atenção.